# How can I find out the classname of an object a closure is bound to?

Tags: php, oop, closures, classname

I've some third party code that creates a closure which gets afterwards bound to an object.
A print_r on the closure object yields this:

```
Closure Object ( [this] => am4Widgets Object ( ) )
```

Now I need to retrieve the 'instanceof' of the bound object (in this case 'am4Widgets'), some kind of pseudocode like

```
print_r(myClosureObject instanceofboundobject am4Widgets);
```

which should output 'TRUE'.

I've searched php.net but to no avail.

Thanks in advance for any idea/suggestion.

UPDATE:

Here is where the closure is created (snippet of code that I cannot modify):

```
function initActions()
{
    parent::initActions();
    .
    .
    .
    add_action('wp_head', function(){
        $ajax_url =  admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' );
        echo <<<CUT
<script>...some javascript code...</script>
CUT;
    });
}
```

Actually, what I'm try to do is to unhook the closure from wp_head because I need it in the footer.

I'm using the global wordpress' $wp_filters to access all registered hook, but now I need a way to uniquely identify the closure I want to unhook, which could be an easy task if there was a way to access the closure's bound object.

Comment: How do you define your «Closure object» ?

Comment: check this: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/137688/remove-actions-filters-added-via-anonymous-functions

Comment: @German Lashevich The "closure", in this case, is built by the wordpress' underlying framework upon the "functio(){}" block passed to the add_action() function as second parameter.

Comment: @yivi Thanks Yivi for the hint. Already found googling around. It's very close to what I'm looking for but not exactly the same. The approach in the first answer will remove _all_ closures within the same priority, whereas I'm looking for a way to remove _only_ the one identified by it's bound object. A dirty hack would be to encapsulate the print_r() call between ob_start() and ob_end_clean() and searching for the string (in my case: am4Widget), but, as said, that's a hack, a dirty hack. I'd rather go for a more OO code approach if possible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`ReflectionFunction`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.reflectionfunction.php) object for that purpose.

```
class A {}

$closure = (function () {
    echo '$this class from closure: ' . get_class($this) . "\n";
})->bindTo(new A());

$closure();

$fn = new ReflectionFunction($closure);
echo '$this class from reflection: ' . get_class($fn->getClosureThis());
```

Output:

```
$this from closure: A
$this from reflection: A
```